# Getting Notification from facebook friends who accepted my invitation request

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api

```
private function InviteMyFriends(e:MouseEvent):void{


            var dat:Object = new Object();
            dat.message = "Let's invite friends for our Super Krish QuizGame Facebook App to get bonus points";
            dat.title   = 'Super Krish QuizGame Facebook App';
            // filtering for non app users only
            dat.filters = ['app_non_users'];
            //You can use these two options for diasplaying friends invitation window 'iframe' 'popup'
            Facebook.ui('apprequests', dat, onUICallback, 'popup');
        }

        private function onUICallback(dat):void{

            var result:Object = dat;
            if(result == null){

                mtline.trace2_txt.text = "User closed the pop up window without inviting any friends";
                return
            }
            var invitedUsers:Array  = new Array();
            invitedUsers = result.request_ids as Array;
            mtline.trace2_txt.text ="You Have Invited " + invitedUsers.length+ " friends";
            //Simple if else if you want user to invite certain amount of friends
            if(invitedUsers.length > 1){
                mtline.trace2_txt.text = "GREAT, USER IS GENERATING TRAFFIC";
            }else{
                mtline.trace2_txt.text = "No Good, User invited only one friend ";
            }
        }
```

Hi,here i have used this code to send my facebook game invitation to my friends using facebook api with action scripting.its working perfectly but i need to identify my friends who accepted my invitation because i have to provide 500 points to the user who send the invitation to his friends after the invitation gets accepted.Kindly help regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That workflow you're proposing is explicitly against Facebook policy and your app could lose the ability to send requests as a result, just be aware of that before you proceed any further.

As for how to track accepted requests, you already have to read and delete the requests when the user clicks 'accept' on them, so you should log at send-time the request IDs and update your records when you're processing the accepted requests